# Как вывести 00:00:00 на таймере обратного отсчета

Tags: javascript, таймер

На писал таймер обратного отсчета. Как сделать так, чтобы при срабатывании `..clearInterval..` время останавливалось на 00:00:00?

```
//timer
        let deadline = "2019-04-13";
        function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
                let t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date()),
                seconds = Math.floor((t/1000) % 60),
                minutes = Math.floor((t/1000/60) % 60),
                hours = Math.floor((t/(1000*60*60)));

            return {
                'total' : t,   
                'hours'  : hours,
                'minutes' : minutes, 
                'seconds' : seconds
                };
        }

        function pad(n) {
            if (n < 10)
                return "0" + n;

             return n;
        }

        function setClock (id, endtime) {
            let timer = document.getElementById(id),
                hours = timer.querySelector('.hours'),
                minutes = timer.querySelector('.minutes'),
                seconds = timer.querySelector('.seconds');
                timeInterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);

        function updateClock() {
                let t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
                hours.textContent = pad(t.hours);
                minutes.textContent =pad(t.minutes);
                seconds.textContent = pad(t.seconds);

                if (t.total <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(timeInterval);
                }
             }
        }
        setClock('timer', deadline);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно обнулять `textContent` для часов, минут и секунд сразу же после вызова `clearInterval`:

```
function updateClock() {
  let t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
  hours.textContent = pad(t.hours);
  minutes.textContent =pad(t.minutes);
  seconds.textContent = pad(t.seconds);

  if (t.total <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timeInterval);
    hours.textContent = "00";
    minutes.textContent = "00";
    seconds.textContent = "00";
  }
}
```